# Set static field value once and use the latest set value in all other threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

As working on multi-threaded application, I have once scenario where I need to assign value to static field. I want to use the latest value of static field in all rest of the threads.

Code is seems like below:

Main() Method:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
  ProcessEmployee processEmployee = new ProcessEmployee();

  Thread thread = new Thread(processEmployee.Process);
  thread.Start(i);
}

public class ProcessEmployee
    {
        public void Process(object s)
        {

            // Sometimes I get value 0 even if the value set to 1 by other thread.
            // Want to resolve this issue.
            if (StaticContainer.LastValue == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Last value is 0");

            }

            if (Convert.ToInt32(s) == 5)
            {
                StaticContainer.LastValue = 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Last Value is set to 1");
            }

            // Expectation: want to get last value = 1 in all rest of the threads. 
            Console.WriteLine(StaticContainer.LastValue);
        }
    }

public static class StaticContainer
    {
        private static int lastValue = 0;

        public static int LastValue
        {
            get
            {
                return lastValue;
            }
            set
            {
                lastValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question:**

Basically, I want to know that once I set specific value to static field *by any thread*, I want to get the *same value* (latest value set by another `thread`) in rest of the `threads` always.

Please do give me any idea on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hint hint: use `volatile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically, I want to know that once I set specific value to static field by any thread, I want to get the same value (latest value set by another thread) in rest of the threads always.

It sounds like you're basically missing a memory barrier. You *could* work this out with explicit barriers but no locks - or you could just go for the brute-force lock approach, or you could use `Interlocked`:

```
private static int lastValue;

public int LastValue
{
    // This won't actually change the value - basically if the value *was* 0,
    // it gets set to 0 (no change). If the value *wasn't* 0, it doesn't get
    // changed either.
    get { return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lastValue, 0, 0); }

    // This will definitely change the value - we ignore the return value, because
    // we don't need it.
    set { Interlocked.Exchange(ref lastValue, value); }
}
```

You *could* use `volatile` as suggested by newStackExchangeInstance in comments - but I'm never actually sure I fully understand *exactly* what it means, and I strongly suspect it doesn't mean what most people think it means, or indeed what the MSDN documentation states. You may want to read [Joe Duffy's blog post on it](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2010/12/04/SayonaraVolatile.aspx) ([and this one too](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/06/13/VolatileReadsAndWritesAndTimeliness.aspx)) for a bit more background.

Comment: Jon - Thanks! Same from my side. As far as I know, we 'could' use volatile if one thread is writing and another thread is reading the value. Seems like my case but I am also NOT sure in depth of Volatile how internally work. Would you please give me detail of your get;set; with Interlocked? I am not getting specially relation with get;set; the way you mentioned with Interlocked.

Comment: @nunu: I'm not sure what you mean - I've given the code, and it should work fine as-is... which bit do you not understand?

Comment: Jon - Thanks again! I got the thing. I was just confused bit in Interlocked.CompareExchange, but now it's clear as I have implemented in my code and works fine... Thanks much for great work!

Comment: @nunu: No problem - it *is* a bit confusing to use an apparently-mutating operation as a *read* operation, but it should work fine :)

Comment: @CharlesKeyser: They can be read *atomically*, but that's not the same as it being "safe" to read them without any memory barriers... you may not see values which have been written by other threads.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just did some research after I posted that comment and realized I confused the two concepts so I removed it, thanks for the clarification though

Answer (score 1):

If two different threads may access the same field/variable and at least one of them will be writing, you need to use some sort of locking. For primitive types use the `Interlocked` class.